# Need program to unbrick usb memory stick

Tags: linux, usb

I have several USB memory sticks with clobbered partition tables (MBR).
When I insert them, they are recognized by Linux as USB mass storage devices, but not as block devices, and I haven't found any char devices yet.

Is there any program that will allow me to write a new MBR on the USB device?
Since they are not recognized as block devices, `gdisk`, `fdisk`, `gparted` can't do so.

Comment: I have no idea if this will work, so I'm going to say this anyway, try giving [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) a shot and use the rebuild MBR function. Let me know if this works for you - they have a [bootable version](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html) in case you can't install the windows application.

Comment: Please include what `dmesg | tail` says when one these memory sticks is inserted.